# How to plot only the current data point from sensor?

Tags: java, processing

I am getting LVDT sensor data from serial port. Data is being stored in variable "values". I am mapping the input and then plotting but it also plots all previous points. I just want to show the latest value.

```
void draw()
{

  while ( myPort.available() > 0) 
  { 
    String values = myPort.readStringUntil(lf);
    if (values != null)
    {

      noFill();
      stroke(255, 0, 0);
      strokeWeight(1);
      float end = map(float(values), 735, 4160, 0, height); // 735 is lowest value from sensor and 4160 is max. value from sensor
      fill(255, 0, 0);
      ellipse(200, end, 10, 10);
      line(200, 400, 200, end);
    }
  }
}
```

Currently it is showing like this:
[image: Current display]

However I want only the latest point to be shown like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a global variable, which stores the last data point. Read the data points at begin of draw and store them the the global variable. This causes that just the last data point is noticed.
Clear the background at the begin of draw ([`background()`](https://processing.org/reference/background_.html)) and draw only this one data point:

```java
String values;

void draw()
{
    while ( myPort.available() > 0) { 
        values = myPort.readStringUntil(lf);
    }

    background(0);
    if (values != null)
    {
        noFill();
        stroke(255, 0, 0);
        strokeWeight(1);
        float end = map(float(values), 735, 4160, 0, height); // 735 is lowest value from sensor and 4160 is max. value from sensor
        fill(255, 0, 0);
        ellipse(200, end, 10, 10);
        line(200, 400, 200, end);
    }
}
```